# How to skip an iteration in a loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I have a for-loop it looks like that:

```
 for (ID in rownames(countDF)) {
      avector <- as.vector(as.numeric(countDF2[rownames(countDF2)==ID,]))
      nbfit <- fitdistr(avector,'negative binomial')
 }
```

So I want to calculate the `fitdistr` function for each of IDs. But the problem is that for some of the IDs the function doesn't work and throws an error. Here it is:

> Error in stats::optim(x = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
>     non-finite finite-difference value [2]

I want to skip these IDs somehow and continue with the others.

I've found a function try, but I don't understand how is it working. 
I've tried it like this:

```
 nbfir <- try(fitdistr(avector,'negative binomial'))
```

But the loop still breaks down with the error. 
What should I do to fix it ?

Comment: `try` still prints the error message, unless you gives it `silent=T`. So are you sure the loop really breaks or you just see some error message but the loop goes to the end?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tryCatch` and do nothing on catching an error.

```
for (ID in rownames(countDF)) {
   avector <- as.vector(as.numeric(countDF2[rownames(countDF2)==ID,]))
  tryCatch(
     nbfit <- fitdistr(avector,'negative binomial'), 
     error = function(e) {})
}
```